# OpenStack: How to make Cloudify use the floating IP instead of the fixed one?

Tags: openstack

I have a problem with Cloudify (both 2.5 and 2.6-rc release). I have an All-In-One Openstack 2013.1.1 setup and I'm trying to use Cloudify to bootstrap a cirros 0.3.1 vm.

My quantum configuration is:

- pool of fixed ip (10.0.0.0/24) for vm management;
- pool of floating ip (192.168.1.170-190) taken from 192.168.1.1/24 (my lan)

When I deploy a vm first, an ip from 10.0.0.0/24 is given (I cannot reach it from my PCs because it is only for vm management) and then I associate a floating ip with which I can ping (and ssh) the deployed machine.

The problem is when I do:

```
bootstrap-cloud openstack
```

because Cloudify stay forever into "attempting to access management vm 10.0.0.3" and this is due to the fact that 10.0.0.3 is not reachable.

What can I do to get Cloudify take the floating ip instead of the fixed one?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure private and public IP addresses in Cloudify as described [here](http://www.cloudifysource.org/guide/2.6/clouddrivers/cloud_driver#ipfilter).

(This works only on Cloudify 2.6).

You also need to:

1. Make sure that your Openstack provider supports auto assignment of floating IPs and that it has a default floating IPs pool name. (i.e.) The following two properties must be set in the `nova.conf` of your OpenStack cloud :

   ```
   default_floating_pool="nova"
   auto_assign_floating_ip = True
   ```
2. Pass `autoAssignFloatingIp : true` in the options of the `computeTemplate` in the OpenStack cloud driver.

   Here's a working example of an Openstack cloud driver: You can use the [cloud driver](https://gist.github.com/tamirko/5887406) and its corresponding [properties file](https://gist.github.com/tamirko/5887423) "as is".

(Disclaimer: I am Tamir Korem, Cloudify Community Manager)